# Keeping Android Menu Items opened after clickng on one of the items

Tags: android, menu

Can I alter the default behavior of the action bar items menu so the menu doesn't close automatically when any of its items is checked ?

I tried returning false to OnOptionsItemSelected method. Also , I tried to add this line to OnCreateOptionsMenu

> ```
>       menu.PerformIdentifierAction(Resource.Id.fs_action_statusFilter, MenuPerformFlags.PerformNoClose);
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a sub menu to an item in your menu by adding a menu element as the child of an item. So the sub menu will open when its parent menu is checked.  For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:id="@+id/file"
         android:title="@string/file" >
         <!-- "file" submenu -->
         <menu>
              <item android:id="@+id/create_new"
                    android:title="@string/create_new" />
         </menu>
   </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: I already have children for each of the menu items but these children are check boxes and thus the user is suffering while trying to check multiple options.